# Using CTE with special conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table for Employee – Manager hierarchy in `SQL Server 2005`.

Following is what I am tring to achieve

[image]

Busienss Logic:

-- Effective Manager should have a department

-- Effective Manager is the nearest manager in the hierarchy who has a department

-- Effective Department is the department of the Effective Manager

I have referred `CTE` for recursive scenarios like this. Example [SQL SERVER – Simple Example of Recursive CTE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/)
But my scenario has more conditions than simply finding the nearest manager.

How can modify this CTE to give the expected result?

QUERY

```
DECLARE @Emploee TABLE (EmpID INT, EmpName VARCHAR(50), Dept VARCHAR(5), Manager INT)

INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (1, 'A', NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (2, 'B', 'D100',NULL)
INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (3, 'C', 'D101',2)
INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (4, 'D', 'D102',1)
INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (5, 'E', NULL,2)
INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (6, 'F', 'D103',5)
INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (7, 'G', NULL,6)
INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (8, 'H', 'D104',7)

SELECT * 
FROM @Emploee
WHERE Manager IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Well - basically - you just take the example and you expand on the FROM and WHERE in your "source" part of the CTE (the first half before the UNION) and you expand on the ON clause after the INNER JOIN in the "second" part of the CTE (the part after the union).

Some rules might be applicable after the recursive functionality - meaning where you actually select from the CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to reduce the CTEs of adrianm answer from 3 to 2 getting the data of the effective manager all together

```
WITH EmployeeManagers AS (
  SELECT e.EmpId, e.EmpName, 1 AS Level
       , e.Manager, e.EmpID CurrLevelEmpID, Cast(Null as VarChar(5)) Dept
  FROM   Employee AS e
  WHERE  e.Manager IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT em.EmpId, em.EmpName, Level + 1 AS Level
       , e.Manager, e.EmpID CurrLevelEmpID, e.Dept Dept
  FROM   EmployeeManagers em
         INNER JOIN Employee e ON e.EmpId = em.Manager
), EffectiveManagers AS (
  SELECT EmpID
       , CurrLevelEmpID Manager
       , Dept
       , Effective = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Level)
  FROM   EmployeeManagers e
  WHERE  DEPT is not null
)
SELECT e.EmpID
     , e.EmpName
     , e.Manager
     , eem.Manager EffectiveManager
     , eem.Dept EffectiveDepartment
FROM   Employee e
       LEFT JOIN EffectiveManagers eem ON e.EmpID = eem.EmpID 
             AND eem.Effective = 1
WHERE  e.Manager IS NOT NULL
```

The `EmployeeManagers` CTE get some more data, in particular `CurrLevelEmpID` is the `EmpID` of the employee at the current level, changing the definition of `e.Manager` will get in the way of the recurring CTE, and `Dept` is the department of the employee at the current level, if there is one.
The `EffectiveManagers` CTE get the row with an effective manager for every employee, `Effective` count the level of the effective manager for the employee line.
The main query `JOIN` the base table with the `EffectiveManagers` getting only the first for every hierarchy (the one with Effective = 1)

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/334a6/25) demo

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH EmployeeManagers AS (
    SELECT Employee.EmpId
          ,1 AS Level
          ,Employee.Manager
    FROM @Employee AS Employee
    WHERE Employee.Manager IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT EmployeeManagers.EmpId
          ,Level + 1 AS Level
          ,Manager.Manager
    FROM EmployeeManagers
         INNER JOIN @Employee AS Manager
             ON Manager.EmpId = EmployeeManagers.Manager
)
,EmployeeManagerDepartment AS (
    SELECT EmployeeManagers.EmpId
          ,EmployeeManagers.Level
          ,EmployeeManagers.Manager
          ,Manager.Dept
   FROM EmployeeManagers
        LEFT JOIN @Employee AS Manager
            ON Manager.EmpID = EmployeeManagers.Manager
)
,EffectiveManagerLevel AS (
    SELECT EmpId
          ,MIN(Level) EffectiveLevel
    FROM EmployeeManagerDepartment
    WHERE Dept IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY EmpId
)
SELECT Employee.EmpID AS [Emp ID]
      ,Employee.EmpName AS [EmpName]
      ,Employee.Manager AS [Direct Manager]
      ,EmployeeManagerDepartment.Manager AS [EffectiveManager]
      ,EmployeeManagerDepartment.Dept AS [Effective Department]
FROM @Employee AS Employee
     LEFT JOIN EffectiveManagerLevel
         ON EffectiveManagerLevel.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
     LEFT JOIN EmployeeManagerDepartment
         ON EmployeeManagerDepartment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
            AND EmployeeManagerDepartment.Level = EffectiveManagerLevel.EffectiveLevel
WHERE Employee.Manager IS NOT NULL
```